# Why the left border of swing looks thicker than others on my PC？

Tags: java, swing

Attention to the JTextField, the left border is a little thicker.
[image]

And this is what it looks like on another PC with the same project
[image]

It doesn't looks like a code problem, yet I can't tell why.

The environment is both under JDK 1.8.0-31, Windows10 Build 10586, eclipse Mars.
It was normal on mine two days ago, but it do happened without any change of code. And it works well if I run it with the exported jar file...

Comment: If you can add some information about both the system, which you have used here, it would be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Different systems use different rendering systems and different properties and settings can change how this works even on similar platforms, this is why we encourage the use of layout managers

Comment: Could be the same problem addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924581/swing-lineborder-thicker-on-one-side

Comment: @camickr It looks like that we are the same but the suggestion doesn't work...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).